# Oracle SQL: How to remove duplicate employee Ids from results?

Tags: oracle

I need to write query to remove duplicate employee ids among 10,000 results

```
EmpID   name

 1       x
 1       x
 2       y
 2       y
 3       z
 4       A
```

The result should be only:

```
EmpID   name

 3       z
 4       A

 Select * from EMPLOYEE where ?
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need aggregation :

```
select e.empid, e.name
from employee e 
group by e.empid, e.name
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: May I ask if you have two accounts? https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/ahmed-abdelhameed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. .  No that account not belongs to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
Select empid,name from EMPLOYEE
group by empid,name
having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really ask you to use other than the `GROUP BY` method  as you will be able to fetch other fields of the `EMPLOYEE` table along with `EMPID` and `NAME`.

Using `analytical function`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT T.*, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID) AS CNT
FROM EMPLOYEE) 
WHERE CNT = 1;
```

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE T
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE TIN 
WHERE TIN.ID = T.ID AND TIN.ROWID <> T.ROWID);
```

Cheers!!